# How can i make a constant size grid-item?

Tags: css, css-grid

This is my HTML/CSS:

```css
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    grid-template-rows:auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto ;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    
}
.grid-container > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    
    
   
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
        <div>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta at earum vel sim jsbf ln.</div>
        <div></div>


    </div>
```

I want to stop grid-item from changing size, the grid item will be bigger if we use more texts in it, i want to make the grid-item constant. How can i do it?

Comment: Set a grid-column width.

Comment: What do you mean with "size": width (column), height (row) or both?

Answer (score 0):

you can change `grid-template-rows` like this:

```css
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    grid-template-rows:repeat(9,50px); ;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    
}
.grid-container > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    
    
   
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div>Lorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloLorem, ipsum doloDicta at earum vel sim jsbf ln.</div>
        <div></div>


    </div>
```

you can also set it for `grid-template-columns` if you wish.